# File not found error when running an exe using Shell function

Tags: vba, excel

I am running a sub from a userform that is supposed to run an exe file, found in the working folder, as follows:

```
Sub RunProcessor()
    If MsgBox("Run simulation?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
      Exit Sub
    Else
      ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path
      Shell ("runsims.exe")
    End If
End Sub
```

This was working fine on my local drive, but started to fail when I moved everything to a server drive (Run-time error 5 on the Shell function call line).

I know in cmd, when you are working on the C: drive and do a `cd L:\...\...\` call, you then need to enter `L:` as well, so I tried to insert this line of code above the other Shell call: `Shell (Left(ThisWorkbook.Path, 2))` but this also failed. How can I have "runsims.exe" run, given that it is always in the current working drive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ChDir` will only work to change the current directory to another on the same drive - you need to use `ChDrive` first if you want to switch to a folder on a different drive.

Better yet, pass the full path to Shell and skip changing the current directory.

```
Sub RunProcessor()
    If MsgBox("Run simulation?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        Shell (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\runsims.exe")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks this works. I wonder why it needs a ChDrive in the first place though, considering this file is saved in the same folder as the exe file.

Comment: You don't need either `ChDrive` or `ChDir` if you pass the full path.  You only need those (to set the "current directory") if you only pass the filename